# meaning of "Emperor of all the Russias"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "all the Russias" mean in:

> To the **Emperor of all the Russias** belongs the supreme autocratic and unlimited power.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*All the Russias* here refers to the following historical regions:

- [*Great Russia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Russia)
- [*Little Russia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Russia)
- [*White Russia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Russia)

Very roughly, this means Russia, Ukraine, and Belarus.  None of these correspond exactly with modern national boundaries, but the Great was the core of Russia, sometimes called "Russia proper"; the Little corresponds mostly to modern Ukraine; and the White corresponds roughly to the eastern half of modern Belarus.

For more details, see the Wikipedia links above.

Answer (score 5):

This is a direct translation of the Russian expression: *Царь Всея Руси*, which was the official title of Russian heads of state starting with [Ivan the Terrible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_the_Terrible). This official title [became a lot longer over time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czar#Full_style_of_Russian_Sovereigns). Similar expressions are used in many languages.

[*Царь*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czar) is often translated by a transliteration: czar (or in modern times [often](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=czar%2Ctsar&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) tsar. There have been [debates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czar#Russia) around the translation of this word; *emperor* is one of the valid possibilities, and later czars did use the title *императоръ* (transliterated: *imperatori*).

*Всея Руси* more properly means [“(of) all Rus'”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_the_Russias). In Russian, *[Русь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C)* and *[Россия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F)* are different words and refer to different stages in the history of Russia and its political and cultural predecessors. *Русь* is translated [Rus'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rus%27_%28region%29) but that term is only used by historians: in most contexts, the word *Russia* is used. The three Rus' (or three Russias) are [Great Russia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Russia) (*Великая Русь*, Moscovy), [Russia Minor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia_Minor) (*Малая Русь*, which became Ukraine) and [White Russia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Russia) (*Белая Русь*, which became the territory and country known as *Белоруссия* (Byelorussia) in Russian and *Белару́сь* ([Belarus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus)) in Belarusian).